# Uncaught (in promise) Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element

Tags: recaptcha

I'm getting an error from a form Submission page like this

**VM656 recaptcha__en.js:276 Uncaught (in promise) Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element**

         **at VM656 recaptcha__en.js:276**

         **at renderRecaptcha ((index):500)**

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution,
A ReCaptcha script call was already on my page and i called the same script again on the same page which causes this conflict.
On the second call to the Recaptcha script, the dedicated div for Recaptcha already got rendered (with the first script call) and this error occurred.

Comment: what did u do to fix it